# How to use ECDSA function in the medtls library

Tags: bitcoin, ecdsa, mbedtls

I am using the mbedtls library (https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls) on an ARM micro-controller (Ambiq).

I need to use the function mbedtls_ecdsa_sign_det() to sign a bitcoin transaction.

Actually, I am not sure if this is the right function.

Here is the documentation of the function:

```
Compute ECDSA signature of a previously hashed message, deterministic version (RFC 6979).

Parameters:
grp ECP group
r   First output integer
s   Second output integer
d   Private signing key
buf Message hash
blen    Length of buf
md_alg  MD algorithm used to hash the message
Returns:
0 if successful, or a MBEDTLS_ERR_ECP_XXX or MBEDTLS_MPI_XXX error code

The header file includes the following description:
/**
 * \brief           This function computes the ECDSA signature of a
 *                  previously-hashed message, deterministic version.
 *
 *                  For more information, see <em>RFC-6979: Deterministic
 *                  Usage of the Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) and Elliptic
 *                  Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)</em>.
 *
 * \note            If the bitlength of the message hash is larger than the
 *                  bitlength of the group order, then the hash is truncated as
 *                  defined in <em>Standards for Efficient Cryptography Group
 *                  (SECG): SEC1 Elliptic Curve Cryptography</em>, section
 *                  4.1.3, step 5.
 *
 * \see             ecp.h
 *
 * \param grp       The context for the elliptic curve to use.
 *                  This must be initialized and have group parameters
 *                  set, for example through mbedtls_ecp_group_load().
 * \param r         The MPI context in which to store the first part
 *                  the signature. This must be initialized.
 * \param s         The MPI context in which to store the second part
 *                  the signature. This must be initialized.
 * \param d         The private signing key. This must be initialized
 *                  and setup, for example through mbedtls_ecp_gen_privkey().
 * \param buf       The hashed content to be signed. This must be a readable
 *                  buffer of length \p blen Bytes. It may be \c NULL if
 *                  \p blen is zero.
 * \param blen      The length of \p buf in Bytes.
 * \param md_alg    The hash algorithm used to hash the original data.
 *
 * \return          \c 0 on success.
 * \return          An \c MBEDTLS_ERR_ECP_XXX or \c MBEDTLS_MPI_XXX
 *                  error code on failure.
 */
int mbedtls_ecdsa_sign_det( mbedtls_ecp_group *grp, mbedtls_mpi *r,
                            mbedtls_mpi *s, const mbedtls_mpi *d,
                            const unsigned char *buf, size_t blen,
                            mbedtls_md_type_t md_alg );
```

Besides, I do not find any example how to use this function.

I do not know how to initialize the passed pointers, grp, r, s and d.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking, an [ECDSA signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) is a pair of two integers (*r*, *s*). The function `mbedtls_ecdsa_sign_det` gives you the two integers `r` and `s` as outputs and it's up to you to decide how you want to output those integers. There are two common representations of ECDSA signatures: take a fixed-size representation of *r* and *s* and put those two together, or assemble them in an [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) sequence, generally in [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) form (ASN.1 admits multiple representations, e.g. with or without leading zeros, and DER is a specific ASN.1 representation, without leading zeros). [Bitcoin uses the DER representation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/why-the-signature-is-always-65-13232-bytes-long). Fortunately for you, Mbed TLS has a function that directly outputs this DER representation: [`mbedtls_ecdsa_write_signature`](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ecdsa_8h.html#a76da70289de1f746ad9cce1eadf7b135).

There are two variants of ECDSA: randomized and deterministic. They produce compatible signatures anyway (the deterministic variant uses a specific choice for the random parameter). `mbedtls_ecdsa_write_signature` uses the deterministic variant if your build supports it and the randomized variant otherwise.

Here's how a call to this function looks like. It takes the following inputs:

- An ECDSA private key `key`.
- A SHA-256 hash to sign `hash`.
- The random number generator which you must initialize at the start of your program (not at each signature generation!). See https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/generate-an-aes-key for an example.

```
unsigned char signature[2 * 32 + 9]; // "at least twice as large as the size of the curve used, plus 9"
size_t signature_length;
ret = mbedtls_ecdsa_write_signature(key, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256, hash, 32,
                                    signature, &signature_length,
                                    mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg);
if (ret == 0) {
    // The signature is in the signature array. It is signature_length bytes long. 
} else ERROR();
```